# Background is shaking in transition

Tags: html, css

I have two div elements that the width can be controlled with click event on javascript. Whether on click event (toggling a className) or hover event, the background images of the its pseudo element seems to be shaking (confirmed on chrome, ie, edge, and safari).

I have looked up on SO and google but it seems to be a problem with changing the size of the background itself, which is what I did not do here.

```css
section {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1920px;
 position: relative;
 min-height: 700px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
 width: 99%;
 height: 700px;
 position: absolute;
 transition: 1s linear width;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: transparent;
 transform: skew(20deg) translateX(-50%);
 border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.left::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100vw;
 transform: skew(-20deg);
 background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/12/04/22/38/road-3856796__340.jpg);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.right {
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
 transform: skew(20deg) translateX(50%);
}

.right::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100vw;
 transform: skew(-20deg);
 background-image: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/taking-a-walk-in-the-woods-picture-id1130258547?s=2048x2048);
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.right:hover {
 width: 250%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container left"></div>
 <div class="container right"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I've tried a lot, but couldn't figure it out. It does not have to do with the screwing, what was my first thought. Have you tried to step back from that pseudo-classing and just putting "real" elements there? It looks, that the browser engine cannot handle this kind of transition even after adding `will-change` or any other animation tweeking.

Comment: So i thought about this. Only think i can think of is if you make the right element a normal container - no transforms - and lay it behind the other element(left). Then on hover right translate left out of the dom. For the white border you can use border right on the left element. You would have to rewrite a bit, but i hope this will help you. The wiggle is because you rescale the right container. I suggest against this because of performance concerns.

Comment: How about this: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/zbWpjB?editors=0100

Comment: @yunzen it seem to do the work but when I change the height of the container it seems that the problem occurs once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have optimized the code and considered the use of left/right to define the size of the element then changed the width transition with a translation.

```css
section {
  max-width: 1920px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  transition:transform 1s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: skew(20deg);
}

.left {
  left: -60vw; /*to create the overflow*/
  right: calc(55% + 10px); /*10px distance between both element*/
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.right {
  right: -80vw;
  left: 45%; /*100% - 55% (the right value of .left)*/
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.left::after,
.right::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -40%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -40%;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transition:transform 1s linear;
}

.left::after {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/12/04/22/38/road-3856796__340.jpg);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.right::after {
  transform-origin: top;
  background-image: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/taking-a-walk-in-the-woods-picture-id1130258547?s=2048x2048);
}

.right:hover {
  transform: skew(20deg) translateX(-60vw);
}

.right:hover::after {
  transform: skew(-20deg) translateX(60vw);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container left"></div>
  <div class="container right"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The shaking stems from the centered `background-position` of the `background-image`.

Let's do this by hand:

Image a `200px` wide `div` and a `background-image` with `200px` width.
The image is set to `center`ed `background-position` and no other background-settings.
The image will then be positioned from `0px` through `200px` of the `div`

Now imaging the same `div` with the same `background-image` and `background-position`.
The only difference is: the div is `201px` wide, that is just 1 more then before.
The image will now be positioned from `0.5px` through `200.5px` of the `div` which will be rounded to `1px` through `201px`

Now one step further: imagine the `width` of the `div` to be `202px` without changing any other properties.
The  image will be positioned from `1px` through `201px`. That's exactly the same as before.

Now because your div is centered. The background starts to shake

(This is not always visible. It depends on the context width);

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let bg = document.querySelector('#bg')

buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    bg.style.width = btn.getAttribute('w')
  })
})
```

```css
#bg {
  display: block;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=990');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<button w="200px">200</button> 
<button w="201px">201</button>
<button w="202px">202</button>

<div id="bg"></div>
```

The solution would be:
The left image should be positioned from the left by `background-position: 0% 50%;` and the right image should be positioned from the right by `background-position: 100% 50%;`

This snippet should be seen in full page view

```css
div {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
div span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
          transform: skew(20deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: at-zb 1s both;
          animation: at-zb 1s both;
}
div span:hover {
  z-index: 200;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation: at-z 1s both;
          animation: at-z 1s both;
}
div span a {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
          transform: skew(-20deg);
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
div span:nth-child(1) {
  left: -160px;
  right: calc(100% / 2 + 10px);
  transition-property: right;
}
div span:nth-child(1) a {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
          transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/800?image=992");
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div span:nth-child(1):hover {
  right: -160px;
}
div span:nth-child(2) {
  left: calc(100% / 2 + 10px);
  right: -160px;
  transition-property: left;
}
div span:nth-child(2) a {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
          transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/800?image=990");
  background-position: 100% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div span:nth-child(2):hover {
  left: -160px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes at-z {
  0% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  1%,99% {
    z-index: 9;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 10;
  }
}

@keyframes at-z {
  0% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  1%,99% {
    z-index: 9;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 10;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes at-zb {
  0% {
    z-index: 10;
  }
  1%,99% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes at-zb {
  0% {
    z-index: 10;
  }
  1%,99% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><span><a></a></span><span><a></a></span></div>
```

See this codepen: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/zbWpjB for a SCSS version

Comment: but in his case the background is applied to a pseudo element where the width is fixed at `100vw` and only the parent container is growing. Logically the pseudo element shouldn't change

Comment: there is still a small shacking when using `1s linear` for the transition, It's probably a kind of bug

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the '.right::after' and '.left::after' elements' width: "100%", instead of basing it on the view size. It seemed to work when done in the dev-tools.

Comment: That will make the the background image stretching and that is not what I want to achieve. I am using 100vw because the left part of the right div's background has to be visible since it contains a content.

Comment: Using vw will cause the image to reshape on different screen-sizes, regardless - but I think Temani Afif's answer solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55185894/revisions

Answer (score 0):

The shaking is the result of using `width: 100vw;` on the element you are resizing. My best guess is that this is causing the height and width of the background image to be recalculated quite a few times during the transistion, so it appears to shake.

You could try using `width: 100%;` instead, but that will cause a different behavior in the way the image resizes.